# Recommender Engine for documents VS Search engine indexing

Tags: clustering, recommender-system, tf-idf

I have a lot of books and I want to make recommendations to users based on the description and the title of those books.

I think that one way is to preprocess the content of the title and description fields (eliminate undesirable words, punctuations), apply the TF-IDF algorithm and then a K-means algorithm to group the books into categories to make recommendations.

However, another approach could be to index all the books using ElasticSearch or Amazon Kendra and build a search engine.

Which approach is better in this case? Is it possible to combine both approaches to improve recommendations?

Comment: Do you have any data on how users interact with the books? Otherwise you cannot make a recommender engine.

Answer (score 1):

Clusters don't help you much, in particular since most likely you'll end up with one huge cluster that contains almost everything and some small clusters that contain mostly duplicates.

So for recommendations use an actual recommender system approach such as NMF. Or use similarity search, of course, based solely on the product descriptions and not on user information.